# "Books & Magazines" in Software Center is empty

Tags: software-center, books

If I go to the Ubuntu Software Center and click on Books & Magazines in the leftmost panel, nothing shows up. I'm connected fine to the Internet, stuff shows up as expected in other sections, and so forth. Is this a bug, or is there just really nothing in there? o_δ

Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPHNH.png), if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [what's available on the related website](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/trusty/books-magazines/). Note especially that the "Available versions" on the left doesn't include Ubuntu 15.10, so it looks like books and magazines have been discontinued.

The reason nothing shows up for you is because the Ubuntu Software Center only shows software from the repositories you've enabled and none of those repositories contain any books or magazines. I'm not really sure which repositories are relevant.